# javascript Regex to allow number and only one space after first three digits

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, ionic-framework

I am working on Angular\Ionic 3 project and I want a regex to validate the phone number that is enter in the Input box.Currently I am able restrict the user to enter only the number but I want 3 digits and then one space and then 7 digits...
e.g) 300 1234567
Below is my HTML code:

```
<ion-input type="tel" 
                  (input)="onKeyPress($event,MobileNoDisplay)" 
                   maxlength="11" 
                   placeholder="300 1122345" 
                   [value]="MobileNoDisplay"
                   [(ngModel)]="MobileNoDisplay">
        </ion-input>
```

OnkeyPress function code:

```
onKeyPress(event,val: string) {

    if (/[\D]/.test(val) ) { 
    this.MobileNoDisplay = val.replace(/[\D]+/g, '');//this will remove any non-
                                                     numerical value
     console.log("MobileNoDisplay-->" + this.MobileNoDisplay);
    }
    else{
      console.log("ELSE CHECK");      
    }

    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

}

Comment: Can u add the attribute pattern ? like `pattern="\d{3}\s\d{7}"`

Comment: `/^\d{3} \d{7}$/.test(val)`

Comment: No it does'nt work it actually replacing the whole thing with empty space after 3 digits...I want to remove any non-numeric value at run time and allow only one space after the first three digits.

Comment: I tried both \d{3}\s\d{7} and /^\d{3} \d{7}$/ and they aren't working either...please check my code am I replacing the val correctly at val.replace??my val.replace works fine with /[\D]+/g though..but seems not working with \d{3}\s\d{7} and /^\d{3} \d{7}$/..

Comment: Maybe with `this.MobileNoDisplay = val.match(/\d{3}\s\d{7}/)[0]`

Comment: No it also does'nt work ...actually /\d{3}\s\d{7}/ is not working at all

Comment: I dont get why it wouldn't, I test it with differents values of val like `let val = '123 1234567'`, `if (/\d{3}\s\d{7}/.test(val) ` and `val.match(/\d{3}\s\d{7}/)[0]` returns the correct input.

Comment: Phone number validation can be quite more complex. You may have a look at https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is admittedly not a pure-regexp solution you asked for but your code sample suggests it's not necessary:

```
// first check if the value does not match the pattern (see the exclamation mark)
if (!/^\d{3} \d{7}$/.test(val)) { 
    // first remove non-digits
    var numeric = val.replace(/\D/g, '');
    // get the first 3 chars, and if the filtered number is longer then 3, add a space, then add the remaining 7 chars, beginning on the fourth char (index 3)
    this.MobileNoDisplay = numeric.substr(0, 3)
        + (numeric.length > 3 ? ' ' + numeric.substr(3, 7) : '');
    console.log("MobileNoDisplay-->" + this.MobileNoDisplay);
}
```

Comment: Its working well when I enter the number in the empty box however when I am removing the numbers it gets stuck at white space character and won't allow me to remove the white space and re-enter the number again??

Comment: @j.doe Fair point, added a condition to check if the filtered number is long enough to add the space.